# Переход на TabBarController из appDelegate.m

Tags: url, callback, objective-c, xcode

В appDelegate.m есть функция обработки URL схемы:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSLog(@"Я до проверки");
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"my application"] == NO) return NO;
    NSLog(@"Я после проверки");
    NSDictionary *d = [self parametersDictionaryFromQueryString:[url query]];

    //От сюда нужно перейти к TabBarController (с возможностью перехода между View Таб бара)
    // Так же нужно вызвать функцию MyFunc с двумя параметрами которые передаются от сюда

    return YES;
}
```

Но я даже не понимаю, как установить таббар, как rootViewController.

Comment: Вы хотите создать TabBar программно или он у вас уже есть в сториборде?

Comment: @Northex, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: В сториборде есть уже, и от него 2 viewControllerа идут.

Answer (score 1):

Программное создание таббара и вставка в него ваших контроллеров (навигейшены можно выбросить, если не нужны):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    //1 tab
    UIViewController *vс1 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle: nil];
    UINavigationController *n1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: vс1];

    //2 tab
    UIViewController *vс2 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *n2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: vс2];

    //3 tab
    UIViewController *vc3 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle: nil];
    UINavigationController *n3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: vc3];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[n1, n2, n3];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Метод у вьюконтроллера лучше вызвать уже в нем в зависимости от того, что нужно сделать, у Вас масса методов, когда Вы можете это сделать:

Создание

```
-init
-initWithNibName:
```

Создание view

```
-loadView
-viewDidLoad
-initWithFrame:
-initWithCoder:
```

Обработка изменения состояния view

```
-viewDidLoad
-viewWillAppear:
-viewDidAppear:
-viewWillDisappear:
-viewDidDisappear:
-viewDidUnload
```

Обработка memory warning

```
-didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

Уничтожение

```
-viewDidUnload
-dealloc
```